# Google Maps Directions API Equivalent URL

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Been searching for an answer, can't find one. I'm using the Google Maps V3 API to get directions and a map. All this is OK ...

But I want to provide a bog-standard A-tag link to the equivalent directions on Google maps itself. I have 2 postcodes. How can I generate a Google Maps directions URL based on 2 postcodes or my

```
 google.maps.DirectionsService
```

I'm going to use the URL to produce a "View on google maps" button and a "printable" button.

Cheers! Aiden

Comment: related?: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the link in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354211/google-maps-query-parameter-clarification)

http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

saddr=

Sets the starting point for directions searches. You can also add text into this in brackets to bold it in the directions sidebar.

daddr=

Sets the end point for directions searches, and again will bold any text added in brackets.You can also add "+to:" which will set via points. These can be added multiple times.

[Example](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=New%20York,NY&daddr=Newark,NJ)

Answer (score 40):

Here are some standard HTML links for different Google Maps functions. [I keep an updated post here.](http://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/)

```
//Spaces can be changed to "+" or encoded as "%20".

//Linking to a location (No directions)
https://www.google.com/maps?q=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204

//No starting point (User input required to generate directions).
https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204

//With a set location as starting point (Automatically generates directions with no user input required).
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204&daddr=314+Avery+Avenue+Syracuse+NY+13204

//With "My Location" as starting point (Automatically generates directions with no user input required).
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204

//Current Location to Latitude and Longitude
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=43.12345,-76.12345

//Query search of a Latitude and Longitude
//Also shows setting a default zoom level
https://www.google.com/maps?ll=43.12345,-76.12345&q=food&amp;z=14

//String search as destination
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=Pinckney+Hugo+Group
```

Comment: I'm not sure how things are being changed, but using My+Location doesn't work, i've used Current+Location instead

Comment: This works well in chrome / firefox / IE11, but i dont see this working in IE9 when one of the parameters is 'My+Location' / 'Current+Location'.

Comment: I see an issue here with IE9 and using 'My+Location' / 'Current+Location'. It seems to search for the actual text instead of interpreting my location - any ideas?

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204

Comment: Nowadays we can use [direction urls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action). For example `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204`. One of the benefits is that it adds a path between the destination and the users location.

Answer (score 4):

As of November 4, 2014 this works on iOS 8 on Safari on iPhone 5C:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/current+location/100 N Arlington Ave, Reno, NV 89509`

It will automatically open Google Maps if installed and take you to the directions chooser screen. Also note: it doesn't matter if you use `%20`, , or `+` for spaces.