# creating a searchbox in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Firstly is it bad to create a navigation bar in HTML with unordered list?
Second it looks bad in the site I want it to be positioned in the right corner and I want to link it with a map but I don't know how that works since this is the first time I'm coding in HTML, so can anyone show me how's that done.

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>

<li>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Location" required="">
    <input type="button" name="Search" value="Search">
  </form>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: -130px;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
}

#nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

form {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: First: it is usual way for creating menus. Second: what you mean by ' not working properly'? P.S. map is google map, i guess?

Comment: As for not working properly I just deleted the part of <a href> in the form element and now it's better. I want to search locations, so yes google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps can take input from `GET` parameters like `https://maps.google.com?q=myquery`, thus:

```
<form method="GET" action="https://maps.google.com">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Location" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, if I search for example Spain, how can I make the google map direct me to Spain. Or is that far more complicated.

Comment: @nor for me `https://maps.google.com?q=Spain` centers the map on Spain... see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354211/google-maps-query-parameter-clarification

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother but my search box is positioned with the menu items and there's a big space in the right part,here's a screenshot http://prntscr.com/hfho00  how can I change that space and position just the search box in the right corner.

Comment: @nor I don't really see that much in the screenshot... maybe `position: fixed; top: 0` or open a new question with a minimal example...